# How to make multiple views in GTK application

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want to make a GTK+ application with multiple views and I don't really know how to achieve it in the best possible way. In every view i need to have some labels and buttons. Firstly I tried to make the appliaction with GtkStack, but StackSwitcher has poor customization options (its buttons are in row and stackswitcher icon's are too small, even with maximum possible size with “icon-size” property).

Connecting stack's page switching with normal buttons would solve the case, but i have no idea how to do such a thing.

My second approach was with multiple windows. I was able to make a few windows and hiding/showing them with buttons. Unfortunately the app will be working on quite bad pc (what's more pc is connected to touchscreen what make it's performance even worse) and after some tests I can say that app has some lags. The whole thing makes all windows in the beggining and then just hide them or show them (depends on what button on which window was pressed).

**To sum up my question:**

1. what is the most optimal way to make such an application? With multiple windows or with GtkStack?
2. If with windows how to optimize the whole thing?
3. if with stack how to implement switchng stack's tab on normal buttons?

Comment: I think you are not explaining yourself correctly, as it seems that what you want is a Window with few containers, check GtkContainer, which is a extremely versatile 'view'. > https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html

Comment: Sorry, I may used the word "view" in the wrong context. I don't realy see how GtkContainer may help with my problem. I don't see in the provided documentation neither in description nor i functions informations that may be helpful. It seems GtkContainer is used mainly to height for width geometry management. I need to do something like GtkStack but without using StackSwitcher.

Comment: I think you are not understanding. You want to handle multiple views, but you are not happy with using buttons t change among them. My suggestion is to use containers means that you can have 3 icons and 3 containers, so everytime you click on an icon, you hide 2 containers and show 1. But

Comment: Well, maybe I'm doing something wrong but this approach doesn't work. Putting containers one on another causes disabling buttons on lower layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer GtkStack. It has awesome `gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name`, which let's you set visible child by it's ID. In the following snippet I use GtkListBox for switching (and I had to store a `GPtrArray` with child names)

```
static void
row_activated (GtkListBox    *box,
               GtkListBoxRow *row,
               gpointer       udata)
{
  MyWid *self = udata;
  MyWidPrivate *priv = self->priv;

  gint row_index = gtk_list_box_row_get_index (row);
  gchar *path = g_ptr_array_index (priv->paths, row_index);

  gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name (priv->stack, path);
}
```

If you want to use `GtkButton` thing are even more simple:

```
gchar *id; // just a string, that allows you to connect buttons and tabs
GtkWidget *child, *button;
child = create_tab_for_id (id); // not a real function! You should define it yourself
gtk_stack_add_named (stack, child, id);
button = create_button_for_id (id); // also not a real function
/* Time for magic */
g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", 
                          G_CALLBACK (gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name),
                          stack);
```

Comment: I like your approach but I have some problems with function used by you. Maybe I should use some additional libraries? When I try to compile i get error:
undefined reference to `create_button_for_id'
Do you know what is missing?

Comment: Ok, I was able to solve the problem with part of your solution. Instead of using `create_button_for_id' I just made normal button connected with function. In function I called gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name and now it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @P.B. Didn't see your comment earlier. `create_tab_for_id` and `create_button_for_id` are placeholders, not real functions. There you create buttons and tabs for given `id`, for example, assign different text to buttons